# Deserializing JSON objects with variable structure, GSON

Tags: json, gson

I'm trying to deserialize JSON with the following structure using GSON:

```
"FKeyColumn": [{
                "ForeignKeyColumns": {
                    "Id": "Id"
                },
                "ReferenceTable": "Expense_Group_Configurations"
            }],

"FKeyColumn": [{
                "ForeignKeyColumns": {
                    "Vid": "Id"
                },
                "ReferenceTable": "Expense_Group_Configurations"
            }]     

           ...
```

I'm not sure how to structure my `ForeignKeyColumns` class though, since the JSON object it represents contains arbitrary key-value pairings (there's no set structure aside from the object always being named ForeignKeyColumns). How can I parse this with GSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It required a custom deserializer for FKeyColumn objects:

```
public class FKeyColumnDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<FKeyColumn> {

          public FKeyColumn deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
              throws JsonParseException {
            final JsonArray jsonFKArray = json.getAsJsonArray();
            final FKeyColumn fkc = new FKeyColumn();

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonFKArray.size(); i++) {
              final JsonObject fkObject = (JsonObject) jsonFKArray.get(i);
              final String ReferenceTable = fkObject.get("ReferenceTable").getAsString();
              final JsonObject ForeignKeyColumns = (JsonObject) fkObject.get("ForeignKeyColumns");

              Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet = ForeignKeyColumns.entrySet();
              for(HashMap.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : entrySet){
                  fkc.fkRefTableMap.put(entry.getKey(), ReferenceTable);
              }
            }


            return fkc;
          }
    }
```